# Castle Windsor: XML Configuration for Dynamic Proxy without a Target

Tags: c#, proxy, castle-windsor

Situation:
I have an interface, such as

```
public interface ITestClass
{
    string StringElement { get; }
}
```

There is an implementation for it:

```
public class TestClassImplementor :
    ITestClass
{
    public string StringElement
    {
        get { return "AAA"; }
    }
}
```

I do have a factory that creates an implementation instance:

```
    public class TestClassFactory
    {
    public ITestClass Create()
    {
    return new TestClassImplementor();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to resolve the implementation using Castle Windsor configuration file (XML), but at the same time not configuring the implementation for the interface.

Why is this needed: resolving (web) services. I do have a (web) service interface, but I don't access the implementation, as it is on another component. I want to be able to simply type `MyCastleUtility.Resolve<ITestClass>()` and get a prepared web service. I want to use Castle Windsor configuration file (XML) to configure the service I'm trying to access.

The problem: if I can't access the implementation, I can't configure it in the configuration file.

What I've tried so far:
1) Factories.

```
        <component id="mycompfactory"
  type="MyTestProject.TestClassFactory, MyTestProject"/>

        <component id="mycomp"
          type="MyTestProject.ITestClass, MyTestProject"
          factoryId="mycompfactory" factoryCreate="Create" />
```

I do get the:
Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentRegistrationException : Type MyTestProject.INewTestClass is abstract. As such, it is not possible to instansiate it as implementation of MyTestProject.INewTestClass service

2) Proxies. Hit the wall when tried to find a way to configure that "proxy must be created for 'ITestClass' interface".

Target: configure Castle Windsor to create interface implementation without directly accessing the class, that implements the interface.

Help is much appreciated,
Mindaugas

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't access the implementation". Why can't you access it? Do you have to use XML?

Comment: > Why can't you access it?
Let's say we have two services in the system: Service1 and Service2. Service1 accesses Service2 via web service interface. Service1 uses Service2's IService2 interface, because Service1 references Service2.Interfaces assembly, but it doesn't directly reference Service2.Application assembly, where the implementation for IService2 interface resides. That's by design and I think that's correct.

> Do you have to use XML?
In general, yes. Components configuration is done in the XML and really wouldn't like to bring an exception in this case, i.e. use code instead of XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the factory approach:

1. Did you also configure the FactoryFacility in your config?
2. In your "mycomp", I think you want to use "service" and not "type":

`<component id="mycomp" service="MyTestProject.ITestClass, MyTestProject"    factoryId="mycompfactory" factoryCreate="Create" />`

Comment: That's it: FactoryFacility configuration!

<facilities>
<facility
id="factory.support"
type="Castle.Facilities.FactorySupport.FactorySupportFacility, Castle.MicroKernel"/>
</facilities>

When this missing piece was added to Windsor configuration file (XML), when I call Resolve on my interface, it hits my factory Create() method, where I can instantiate interface implementation the way I like.

Btw, I left 'type' for my interface, didn't change it with 'service', as changing it gives me "No component supporting service ITestClass was found" during component resolution.

Comment: Cool.  I guess Windsor is smart enough to know what you mean since you're using a factory.

Comment: re: "No component supporting service ITestClass was found" - this looks like a bug in Windsor, which simply ignores components that do not have 'type' specified when reading XML. I'll see if I can fix that for v2.5

Comment: Is there a way to configure a call to a factory' generic Create method (for example: CreateGeneric<TService>(..)), by passing the generic from 'mycomp'? In my case generic TService would have a IBaseClass constraint and I would (like to) pass the ITestClass from 'mycomp' configuration (image that ITestClass implements base interface IBaseClass).